# Not returning an array - Rails model function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailchimp

I have a method in my model `Post` like this:

```
def self.post_template
    posts = Post.all
    result = []

    posts.each do |post|
        single_post = {}
        single_post['comment_title'] = post.comment.title
        single_post['comment_content'] = post.comment.content

        result << single_post
    end

    # return the result
    result
end
```

In one of my rake tasks, I call the function:

```
namespace :post do
    task :comments => :environment do
        comments = Post.post_template
        puts comments
    end
end
```

In the console, the return value isn't an `Array`; instead, it prints all the hashes separated by a newline:

```
{ 'comment_title' => 'stuff', 'comment_content' => 'content' }
{ 'comment_title' => 'stuff', 'comment_content' => 'content' }
{ 'comment_title' => 'stuff', 'comment_content' => 'content' }
```

However, when I run this in my `rails console`, I get the expected behavior:

```
> rails c
> comments = Post.post_template
-- [{ 'comment_title' => 'stuff', 'comment_content' => 'content' }, 
   { 'comment_title' => 'stuff', 'comment_content' => 'content' }]
```

Needless to say, I'm pretty confused and would love any sort of guidance! Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Seems rake tasks simply print out arrays like this, but when I set the result of my array into another hash, it does not seem to maintain the integrity of the array:

```
namespace :post do
    task :comments => :environment do
        comments = Post.post_template

        data = {}
        data['messages'] = comments
    end
end
```

I'm using `Mandrill` (plugin for `Mailchimp`) to create these messages and it throws an error saying that what I'm passing in isn't an `Array`.

Comment: Just FYI, it's unsafe to do `Post.all.each`. It's better to say `Post.find_each(batch_size: 50)` (`batch_size` can be however long) so you don't load a huge object into memory

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm actually deleting the posts periodically in a separate rake task so [hopefully] I don't run into that exact problem :]

Comment: In response to your edited question, can you post the result of `puts comments.class`? It should be an array... Also I'm not exactly sure what you're talking about when you say "to create these messages". Which messages?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's just how rake prints arrays. Try this:

```
task :array do
    puts ["First", "Second"]
end
```

Now:

```
> rake array
First
Second
```

Comment: So if I have to put the result of `Post.post_template` into a hash in a rake task, how would can I maintain the array? See edited question.